# Is it possible to simulate running CF Standard with the Developer version?

Tags: coldfusion

Adobe's documentation on restricted features isn't always as complete as I'd like. Occasionally, I end up testing something in the Developer version, only to find out later it's throttled in CF Standard.

Out of curiosity, is there any way to simulate running CF Standard, if you're using the CF Developer version?

Comment: I am thing threading limits are lower on standard. Can't think of anything else

Comment: Have you asked on the Slack channel? One of the Engineers might be able to answer this one.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Actually [there are quite some differences in feature availability](https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html).

Comment: @Shawn - No, but that is a good idea.

Comment: @Ageax if you have a CF standard, license number, you can certainly use that locally.

Comment: @AdrianJMoreno - There's a thought... I have one that's in use at the moment. Do you know if I have to remove it from that machine, before using it locally? I only want to run a few tests, but don't want to mess up the other install.

Comment: Forgot to ask, what version of CF? Adrian's right. I'm pretty sure that a single license can be used in both Production and one instance of Dev as long as the Dev isn't internet-accessible. At least it was that way through CF2016. Don't know if that changed for CF2018.

Comment: And RE: Dev disabling the existing Prod license, if it's not connected to the same network, it shouldn't be able to see that there's another instance anyway. Regardless, I think the question as asked also needs a good answer. If there are 2 devs working in different locations on the 1 Prod license, how can they use Developer version to test a Standard Prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general consensus seems to be this is not currently possible. There's an open enhancement request for this feature, [CF-4205026](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4205026).

> Allow the developer installation to switch between which licence type
>   it should be running as (Standard or Enterprise) so that local
>   development better resembles production.

Hopefully it'll get enough votes and will be added in a future update.